# Server side SSL socket in Visual Basic (VB6)

Tags: sockets, ssl, vb6

I have to edit an existing VB6 application that deals with Socket requests from client endpoints. What are tools (Classes/methods) that allow one to make an SSL Socket instead of a classic socket. I found out that there is a control called WinSock, but I don't know whether it is suitable for the server's tasks or not.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: The stock Microsoft Winsock control has no SSL support.  If this is really a requirement you might consider a 3rd party alternative.  There are several still marketed.

Comment: An alternative would be to create a .Net assembly that you'd call from your vb6 app via com interop.  You could then use the sslstream class to support SSL/TLS on a tcp socket.  See [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: How to call a 3rd party from my vb6 app  ?